# why listview items are disabled initially?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have the following as the layout of each item in a ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But each time I'm getting this:

[image]

As you can see, both buttons as well as TextViews are disabled (take a look at their appearance). Please note that each individual item in ListView takes action when I click them (I've defined OnItemClickListener()); the only problem (so far) is the appearance of buttons and textviews. Here's main_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:hint="Text empty"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="9" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you edit your question and add your ListView xml Layout and your java class of adapter?

Comment: what do you mean by disable? do you want to say that your listView item's onItemclick is not triggering?

Comment: I edited my question. and by "disabled" I meant what you're seeing. The "APPEARANCE" of buttons tells what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine only. The screen is disabled because when the emulator opens, you should use it. If you kept it in idle, it will hide these controls. when you click anywhere inside the screen of the emulator. It will take control.

Comment: That's not the case. Just take a look at the first view (TextView): it's enabled!

Comment: can you add the list view in your xml layout. becoz I checked your code. It's working fine only. Edit in your question

Comment: Still Can't get your full xml code. Edit as a single xml file to get all TextView, ListView, EditText and Buttons.